# Problem viewing cucumber html reports generated via Karate on another machine

Tags: html, cucumber, reporting, portability, karate

I am able to successfully generate & view cucumber html reports after running my Karate tests on my local machine. However, i am unable to share these reports with others since the rich content is getting lost when the report is sent/shared to/with others.
what should i do, so that others can view the reports the same way as i do? Publishing it on Web would be great, but don't know how to implement it in the current scenario.

Tried uploading the html report on Sharepoint & sharing the link with others --didn't help.

The html reports should be centrally placed, so that anyone could view the reports & its full rich content from any machine. Hosting of report on web would be great, since it will then be accessible for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the job of the CI tool and Karate does not need to be in the report distribution business. Many teams use the [Jenkins HTML publisher plugin](http://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin), you should be able to find something similar.